# Unable to create data in a linked table

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have some troubles inserting data in my postgres database from SQLAlchemy.
My schema is quite simple:

It is composed by a table **process** which has two attributes (**pk_process** (PK) and **version**) and a table general_metadata which has also two attributes (**fk_process** (PK and FK) and **name**).
Here's the code:

```
import uuid

from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Text, text, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base import UUID
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

CONNEXION_URL = 'postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/elsa_data_test'

engine = create_engine(CONNEXION_URL, echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata


class Process(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'process'

        pk_process = Column(UUID, primary_key=True)
        fk_person = Column(UUID, nullable=False)
        version = Column(Text, nullable=False)


class GeneralMetadata(Process):
    __tablename__ = 'general_metadata'

    fk_process = Column(ForeignKey('process.pk_process', ondelete='CASCADE', onupdate='CASCADE', match='FULL'),
                        primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)

    process = relationship("Process")


process = Process(pk_process=uuid.uuid4().hex, fk_person=uuid.uuid4().hex, version='V1')
session.add(process)

general_metadata = GeneralMetadata(process=process, name='meta_name')
# process.general_metadata = general_metadata          I also tried this

session.add(general_metadata)

session.commit()
```

I cannot figure out why but whenever I try to commit I get :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError)
ERREUR:  une valeur NULL viole la contrainte NOT NULL de la colonne « pk_process »
DETAIL:  La ligne en échec contient (null, null, null)
[SQL: 'INSERT INTO process (fk_person) VALUES (%(fk_person)s) RETURNING process.pk_process'] [parameters: {'fk_person': None}]
```

If I comment the two lines that creates and add `general_metadata`, the commit works and an instance of process is created.

Is it something work in the way I create or associate objects?

Comment: Your usage example and error details refer to the `fk_person` filed which is not present in the `Process` table definition. Is your example incomplete?

Comment: Indeed... I minimalized my exemple a bit too much. I just edited it. The problem is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understood why i got this error.

My GeneralMetadata class inherits from Process and not from Base.

Changing this solved everything.